# ExtJS TextField Enter Key After Click External Button

Tags: extjs

I want to call button click in textfield enter function.

```
items: [
{
    xtype: 'form',
    id: 'myForm',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id: 'myTextField',
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(f,e){
                if(e.getKey() == e.ENTER){
                    console.log('Spacial Key = Enter'); // It's working
                    // But i wanna click btnSearch button click event
            }
            }
        }
    }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Search',
            id: 'btnSearch',
            handlers: function(){
                // bla bla
                // bla bla
                // ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
]

var myform = Ext.getCmp('myForm');
myForm.getForm().submit()
```

It's working but btnSubmit.click function not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.getCmp('btnSearch').focus();
```

I Dont Think It But Its Working For Me :)

Thanks For All

Answer (score 2):

this code working  :

```
    {
                            fieldLabel : 'Password',
                            name : 'j_password',
                            inputType : 'password',
                            allowBlank : false,
                            listeners : {
                                'render' : function(cmp) {
                                    cmp.getEl().on('keypress', function(e) {
                                        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                                            submitform();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to create a method like `doSearch()` and call this method from both handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you scope you can try this:

```
Ext.getCmp("btnSearch").handler.call(Ext.getCmp("btnSearch").scope);
```

Comment: i try it but i use waiting message on search and use form.submit() function. its clicked but not send form. but .focus() works for me. thank you